# How to extract "infobox company" data from wiki dumps

Tags: java, xml, parsing, wikipedia

I have downloaded a big wiki dump XML file from https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20170520/

I want to extract the metadata company name and parent company from this wikidumps. All the company data are located in the XML template like below:

```
{{Infobox company
| name =
| logo = 
| type = 
| industry = 
| fate = 
| predecessor = <!-- or: | predecessors = -->
| successor = <!-- or: | successors = -->
| founded = <!-- if known: {{Start date and age|YYYY|MM|DD}} in [[city]], [[state]], [[country]] -->
| founder = <!-- or: | founders = -->
| defunct = <!-- {{End date|YYYY|MM|DD}} -->
| hq_location_city = 
| hq_location_country = 
| area_served = <!-- or: | areas_served = -->
| key_people = 
| products = 
| owner = <!-- or: | owners = -->
| num_employees = 
| num_employees_year = <!-- Year of num_employees data (if known) -->
| parent = 
| website = <!-- {{URL|example.com}} -->
}}
```

I did some research and found about MediaWiki Parser. 
Reference: https://github.com/dkpro/dkpro-jwpl/blob/master/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia.parser/src/main/java/de/tudarmstadt/ukp/wikipedia/parser/tutorial/T1_SimpleParserDemo.java

https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-jwpl/JWPLParser/

I tried to use this parser. But it requires the file to be converted in string. My wiki dump XML file is 60 GB in size. I can't convert this big file in string and keep in memory. Also, there is no description for the Mediawiki parser on how to find specific element like **Infobox company**, go inside it and extract name and other fields. Below is the sample code for Mediawiki parser:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File file = new File("C:/Users/njaiswal/Downloads/accenture_data_from_wikidumps.xml");
    String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);

    // get a ParsedPage object
    MediaWikiParserFactory pf = new MediaWikiParserFactory();
    MediaWikiParser parser = pf.createParser();
    ParsedPage pp = parser.parse(str);
    // get the sections


    for (Section section : pp.getSections()) {
        System.out.println("section : " + section.getTitle());
        System.out.println(" nr of paragraphs      : " + section.nrOfParagraphs());
        System.out.println(" nr of tables          : " + section.nrOfTables());
        System.out.println(" nr of nested lists    : " + section.nrOfNestedLists());
        System.out.println(" nr of definition lists: " + section.nrOfDefinitionLists());


      for (Link link : section.getLinks(Link.type.INTERNAL)) {
          System.out.println("  " + link.getTarget());
      }
}

}
```

Is there any other parser that can solve my problem? Or can I use the same MediaWiki Parser to get to "Inbox company" and extract fields? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Update: I tried to use wikiXMLj parser that Khalil suggested. I am able to get all the "Infobox" data, but I want to limit this to "Infobox company" data. Below is my code and output:

```
import edu.jhu.nlp.wikipedia.*;
    public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        WikiXMLParser parser = WikiXMLParserFactory.getSAXParser("C:/Users/njaiswal/Downloads/enwiki-20170520-pages-articles-multistream.xml/enwiki-20170520-pages-articles-multistream.xml");
            parser.setPageCallback(new PageCallbackHandler() {
                public void process(WikiPage page) {
                  try {
                    InfoBox infobox=page.getInfoBox();
                    System.out.println(infobox.dumpRaw());
                } catch (WikiTextParserException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                   //do something with info box
                }
            });
            parser.parse();
    }

}
```

O/P:

```
{{Infobox Monarch
| name            = Attila
| title           = [[List of Hunnic rulers|Ruler]] of the [[Hunnic Empire]]
| place of burial = 
}}
{{Infobox sea
| name = Aegean Sea
| image = Aegean Sea map.png
| caption = Map of the Aegean Sea
| pushpin_map = World
| pushpin_map_alt = World
| pushpin_label_position = right
}}
{{Infobox company
| name             = Audi AG 
| logo             = Audi-Logo 2016.svg
| logo_size = 235
| image            = Audi Ingolstadt.jpg
| image_size = 265
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used before [wikixmlj](https://code.google.com/archive/p/wikixmlj/) very simple dumb parser.  this shall parse it perfectly:

```
// dumpPath should be like C:\your/Path/articles.xml.bz2"
WikiXMLParser wxsp = WikiXMLParserFactory.getSAXParser(dumpPath);
wxsp.setPageCallback(new PageCallbackHandler() {
    @Override
    public void process(WikiPage page) {
        //System.out.println("info box:" + page.getInfoBox());

       String regex = "\\{{Infobox company(.|\\n)+";
       Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
       Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(page.getInfoBox());
       while (matcher.find()) {
       System.out.println(matcher.group(0));}

}
    });
    wxsp.parse(); }
```

[demo of the regex](https://regex101.com/r/5OXSQ6/1)

Comment: Thanks, Khalil. I will try this and let you know

Comment: Hi Khalil, I tried your approach. I able to get Infobox with all the data. Is there anyway that I can get access to only "Infobox company" data?

Comment: Please check my updated question. I have added my query

Comment: @NupurJaiswal prpably you can get infobox now by processing the infobox as a String